# Capture a Stereo Image from dual back camera setup

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm trying to capture a stereo video feed from the dual camera setup on Redmi Y2.

Unfortunately, It hasn't been updated to Android P yet and hence doesn't seem like multi-camera support has officially come by Google yet. I was wondering if there is any other way to capture a stereo feed.

I tried using this very simple code to detect cameras at least but it only detects a single front and back camera despite having a dual camera setup on both sides.

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<String> camID = new ArrayList<>();

        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        try {
            for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
                camID.add(cameraId);
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(camID.size()),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```